# Coding issue I need help seeing my error and correcting it

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Balance2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your monthly deposit amount: ");
        double value = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the annual interest rate: ");
        double annualRate = input.nextDouble();
        double monthlyRate = annualRate / 1200;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of months: ");
        int numMonths = input.nextInt();
        for (int month = 1;month <= numMonths;month++){
            double interest = (value*monthlyRate)/(1-Math.pow(monthlyRate,numMonths));
            value += interest;
            System.out.println("Balance at end of month " + month + " is " + df.format(value));
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is that  whenever it prints value does not update properly and I need it to go from 1008.33  to 8305.91 in month 8 I just figure out what Im doing wrong
Inputs:
Monthly deposit: 1000
Annual interest rate: 10
number of months: 8
Real outcome :end of month 1 is 1008.33, month 8 is 1068.64
expected outcome: end of month 1 is 1008.33, month 8 is 8305.91
I believe the reason this is happening lays somewhere in the formula I have to get the monthly balance.

Comment: Please show your observed and expected outputs, and explain 1) why you expect such outputs and 2) what debugging you have done, and what it has shown you.

Comment: Please share your inputs, and the expected output

Comment: are you trying to compute compound interest?

Comment: After your question edit: Seems that you're not doing the "monthly deposit" part, but only an "initial deposit". I.e. you should add a new "double total" and in your loop add the `value` every iteration to simulate the "monthly deposit" part. HTH

Comment: Not really compound it goes by month, so month 1 is 1008.33 and month 8 should be 8305.91

Comment: **Why** should month 8 be  8305.91? Try to explain in words what the algorithm is supposed to do, because at the moment we only have the same information the computer has, so will come to the same answers it does.

Comment: @AustinDerek please tell me what you are trying to do as if i'm clueless on finance math. also, test your math on excel or any spreadsheet tools you have.

Comment: So the monthly deposit will always be 1000 then the formula will take that 1000 multiply it by the monthly rate, and divide it by the monthly rate to the power of the number of months it increases at a certain rate that the final amount at month 8 is 8305.91

Comment: month 1: 1008.33, month 2: 2025.07, month 3: 3050.28, month 4: 4084.03, month 5: 5126.40, month 6: 6177.45, month 7: 7237.26, month 8: 8305.91.

Comment: i tried [fd calculator](https://www.calculator.com.my/fd-savings) i found online, it spew the same number for the 8th month result. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have the formula wrong.

There are two ways to compute the final balance.

- The iterative approach.  Perform the interest calculations as the bank would

  ```
  month 0: balance_0 = 1000
  month 1: balance_1 = balance_0 + interest on balance_0 + 1000
  month 2: balance_2 = balance_1 + interest on balance_1 + 1000
  ```

  and so on, until you get to month 8

  The interest for each month is the balance at the start of the month x the monthly interest rate.  (The monthly interest rate is the yearly interest rate / 12)
- The algebraic approach.  You find the formula for computing interest compounded over a number of months with a monthly deposit.  Then plug in the values.

  ```
  month 8: balance = "some algebraic formula that involves 
                      raising something to the power of something".
  ```

  (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.or/wiki/Compound_interest#Investing:_monthly_deposits) for the actual formulae.   If you are interested.)

What you seem to have done is take a formula with a power term and plugged it into an iteration.

Solution: use the iterative approach but do the monthly interest calculation as I described above.

Comment: This would not work as it's a program used to calculate based on the number of months I enter, so if I enter 12 months it would print for all 12 months.